# PostgreSQL WHERE inside a CASE expression

Tags: postgresql, conditional-statements, case, where-clause

Say I have this table below:

| month | num_of_fruits | gain |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 5 | 4 |
| 2022-02-01 | 10 | 5 |
| 2022-03-01 | 9 | 8 |

I'm looking to create a query based on a calculation. Is it possible to put a WHERE condition inside a CASE expression? The calculation for it is:
`Set the 'test' column as num_of_fruits / this month's gain + previous month's gain.`

Now the calculation is a bit weird for each month:

- January will be `num_of_fruits / this month's gain + previous month's (Dec) gain`
- February will be `num_of_fruits / this month's gain + previous month's (Jan) gain + December of last year's gain`
- March will `num_of_fruits / this month's gain + previous month's (Feb) gain + 2 months ago's (Jan) gain + December of last year's gain`
- The rest follows the same format where it sums the gains of the current month until December of last year's

I tried to come up with a query in PostgreSQL for just the month of January:

```
CASE 
    WHEN "month" = '2022-01-01' THEN num_of_fruits / ("gain" + "gain" WHERE (date_trunc('month', "month" - interval '1 month')))
END "test"
```

I know it's possible to have a calculation after the THEN clause, but is it possible to have a condition there (i.e. getting the gain value of last month's or any previous month's)?

Are there other solutions? Any tips, advice, or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Don't use `CASE` for this. It sounds like you're looking to use `SUM` as a window function.

Comment: How will I be able to get the previous months' `gain` column though?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/tutorial-window.html - it sounds like you want `SELECT *, num_of_fruits / SUM(gain) OVER (ORDER BY month) AS test`